# For eigenvector $Hv= \lambda v$, $(H-\lambda)(\{v\}^{\perp}) \subseteq \{ v\}^{\perp}$ and $H-\lambda$ is invertible on $\{ v\}^{\perp}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-field-theory

Literally, let $H : \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ be an operator of Hilbert space, or finite dimensional inner product space. Assume that $H$ has an eigenvector $\lambda$ with unit eigenvector $v$. Then $(H-\lambda)(\{v \}^{\perp}) \subseteq \{ v\}^{\perp}$ ( the orthogonal complement of $v$ ) and the restriction of $H-\lambda$ to  $\{ v\}^{\perp}$ is invertible on that space? If this is not true in general, then when is true? How about the case that $H$ is self adjoint ( or normal )? I have been struggled with this for hours and not prove until now. Is there a counter example?

P.s. My question originates from following argument in Folland, Quantum field theory, a tourist guide for mathematician, p.127 :

[image]
[image]

Why the underlined statement is true?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do we know that $\lambda$-eigenspace is only one-dimensional?

Comment: I think that $\lambda$-eigenspace may have dimension larger than $1$, unless special conditions are imposed. As Robert Israel answered below, if the $\lambda$-eigenspace has dimension $1$ and $H$ is normal and $\mathcal{H}$ is finite dimensional inner product space, then I think that we can prove our question by using spectral theorem. And why Folland did claim that the underlined statement is true? Is there a possibility of existence of more general situation still to guarantee our statement?

Comment: Notice he says that having $\lambda$ be simple is needed for things to work.

Comment: O.K. Thanks. Looking closerly, he wrote that "for example, ~~$\lambda_0$ is simple ". Assuming this, although $\mathcal{H}$ is general Hilbert space, our question will be true? :)

Answer (score 2):

The statement is true if $H$ is a normal operator on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space and $\lambda$ is a simple eigenvalue, i.e. the null space of $H - \lambda$ is one-dimensional.  Counterexamples when $H$ is not normal or $\lambda$ is not simple are easy to find on $2 \times 2$ matrices.

If the Hilbert space is infinite-dimensional, it can happen that the inverse of the restriction of $H-\lambda$ to $\{v\}^\perp$ is unbounded, so in that sense this restriction is not "invertible".

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing out. As you said, if the eigenspace of $\lambda$ has dimension $1$, then it can be used as key point to prove our statement, using the Spectral Theorem ( Friedberg, Linear Algebra, Theorem 6.25 ). Thank you. And in the origination of our question - Folland's book - , why he did asserted that the restriction of $H_0 -\lambda_0$ to the orthogonal complement of $v_0$ is invertible? In quatum field theory, usually given an operator its domain is ( possibly infinite dimensional ) Hilbert space.. Perhaps, is there more general condition to guarantee our statement?

Comment: It's true if $\lambda$ is an isolated point of the spectrum.

Comment: Where can I find assoicated proof?